# How to get Generic's T type in sonarqube plugin writing?

Tags: variables, generics, plugins, sonarqube

I am writting java plugin in sonar, here is a problem:

```
class MyThemeRes
{
    private SoftReference<Context> mThemeResContextRef = null;
    // ...
}
```

in this class, How to get Generic's T type? please give some example. 
thanks very much.

Comment: i am writing plugin rules for java check.

Comment: can you please precise a bit your question ? I actually have no clue what you are trying to achieve. Are you writing a custom rule ? You want to access the symbol or type of the parameter type of the type of your variable in your example ? So i'm guessing you are trying to use semantic API ? (please note that there is nothing called T in your example so your question is rather unclear)

Comment: Dear Mr benzonico, yes, I am writing a custom rule for java check based on sonar-java-3.6, and in this example, the 'T' i means here is 'Context', but how to get it?